# Why doesn't unittest recognize SQLAlchemy data type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-3.7, python-unittest

I've written a function that returns a SQLAlchemy data type along with the parameters of that type. But, when I try to test that function, unittest tells me that the type my function returns doesn't match the type I'm expecting. However, it seems to be showing me that the function's return, and my expected result DO match.

Simplified code example...

```
from sqlalchemy import Numeric

class TestStandardizeColDataTypes(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_successful_numeric(self):
        self.assertEqual(standardize_col_data_type('Dec'), Numeric(precision=12, scale=2))
```

Here is what the unittest results show (via Pycharm)...

```
Numeric(precision=12, scale=2) != Numeric(precision=12, scale=2)

Expected :Numeric(precision=12, scale=2)
Actual   :Numeric(precision=12, scale=2)
```

It sure looks like these are equal. I've tried changing the test type to AssertIs and AssertIsInstance without any luck.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add your implementation of ```standardize_col_data_type()```

Comment: this has nothing to do with `unittest`

Comment: @aws_apprentice But isn't it unittest that's not responding as I expected it to?

Comment: The `Numeric` class probably doesn't define `__eq__` so `unittest` has no way to know if the 2 objects are actually the same or not. You're better off comparing the precision and scale manually.

Comment: @rdas I just tried your suggestion and it worked! Would you like to post it so I can mark it as correct or should I post the code that seems to work?

Comment: @Ben there already seems to be an answers with the necessary info. Mark that as accepted instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @aws_apprentice said is correct. An easy workaround, however, is to compare the two objects' attribute dictionaries returned by the `vars` function instead:

```
self.assertEqual(vars(standardize_col_data_type('Dec')), vars(Numeric(precision=12, scale=2)))
```

This avoids having to hard-code the name of each attribute individually for comparison.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you are trying to compare equality between two objects which do not have the `__eq__` method implemented. You can see that in the docs as show [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py#L519).

The reason for this behavior is as follows:

> > User-defined classes have **eq**() and **hash**() methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and x.**hash**() returns an appropriate value such that x == y implies both that x is y and hash(x) == hash(y).

You can find that described in more detail [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)

One option would be to make a custom class which inherits from the `Numeric` type and defines a `__eq__` method. 
Another option would be what @rdas mentions in his comment:

> > You're better off comparing the precision and scale manually.